# Mysql, tree, Hierarchical query, performance

Tags: mysql, performance, tree, hierarchical

My question is based on the following article (the table and the function hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id) http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Lets assume that the table t_hierarchy has two additional fields (beside id and parent) typ1(char) and time(int). the field typ1 can have two values A and B.
My goal is to display the whole tree as described in the article but I need an extra field in the result that displays the time of the current node (if typ1 = B) and of all of its descendants (if typ1 = B). So I need the sum of all descendants' times for a certain node (including itself) when typ1=B.

I have the following solution but it is way too slow:

main query:

```
 SELECT  CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', level - 1), hi.id) AS treeitem, get_usertime_of_current_node_and_descendants(hi.id) as B_time,
        hierarchy_sys_connect_by_path('/', hi.id) AS path,
        parent, level
FROM    (
        SELECT  hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id(id) AS id,
                CAST(@level AS SIGNED) AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @start_with := 0,
                        @id := @start_with,
                        @level := 0
                ) vars, t_hierarchy
        WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
        ) ho
JOIN    t_hierarchy hi
ON      hi.id = ho.id
```

The function get_usertime_of_current_node_and_descendants(input int):

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _id INT;
        DECLARE _desctime INT;
        DECLARE _nodetime INT;
        SET _id = input;

select COALESCE((select sum(time) from (
                SELECT   hi.id, time,typ1
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id_2(id) AS id, @levela AS level
                        FROM    (
                                SELECT  @start_witha := _id,
                                        @ida := @start_witha,
                                        @levela := 0,
                                ) vars, t_hierarchy a
                        WHERE   @ida IS NOT NULL
                        ) ho
                JOIN    t_hierarchy hi
                ON      hi.id = ho.id
                ) q where typ1 = 'B'), 0) into _desctime;
select COALESCE((select time from t_hierarchy where id = _id and typ1='B'), 0) into _nodetime;
return _desctime + _nodetime;

END $$
```

The function hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id_2 is the same as in the article and as the one above hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id but it has differently named global variables so it won't interfere with the the ones used in the main query.

The above solution works as desired but it is way too slow (especially when working with large datasets). Can you offer a better solution or can you suggest how to improve the query? Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: unfortunately using nested sets is not an option

Comment: What you can do is to use a fixed tree depth, for example 4 and then use joins in the query. I did this for an adjacent tree of depth 4 and it should be faster then recursivley query the tree. Of course it looks ugly and it's not so flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem retrieving the time of the descendants outside of mysql (before inserting the entries into the table).

Comment: I know you can't vote but can you please accept my answer? I give you suggesstion to use a fixed depth and I think this isn't a worthless answer! Thank you!

Comment: The comment/answer is not suitable for the above described case because it is not a fixed depth tree. The tree in the linked article is also not a fixed depth tree. The depth is variable. But if it were a fixed depth tree I would most likely use your solution. I certainly did not intend to ignore or discredit your answer.

Comment: This is not a nice answer but know that I know I won't help you anymore.